# Copy userContent folder using the Jenkins workflow plugin

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow

I am trying to build a new pipeline a I need to copy the files that I have in the userContent folder of jenkins to the workspace.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest approach is to install the [Git userContent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+userContent+plugin). At that point you can probably do something like (untested):

```
node {
  git "${env.JENKINS_URL}userContent.git"
}
```

Comment: Currently I am not using git I am using the direct http for userContent. It works but feels like a workaround, I was looking for something similar to what we have now in jenkins normal tasks

Comment: Which “normal tasks”? And did you try the approach I recommended?